# How to reduce the cobalt memory usage when play 4k video

Tags: memory, cobalt

I'm porting cobalt release_11 (11.119147) to my STB .

I want to reduce the cobalt memory usage when play 4K Video to the 180M .
Cobalt will add about 140M of memory(all 250M memory) when playing 4K video from the youtube homepage,  most are used as media buffer to cache demuxer media data.
I find the base.gypi have a parameter config: cobalt_media_buffer_storage_type as follows:

```
# This can be set to "memory" or "file".  When it is set to "memory", the
# media buffers will be stored in main memory allocated by SbMemory
# functions.  When it is set to "file", the media buffers will be stored in
# a temporary file in the system cache folder acquired by calling
# SbSystemGetPath() with "kSbSystemPathCacheDirectory".  Note that when its
# value is "file" the media stack will still allocate memory to cache the
# the buffers in use.
'cobalt_media_buffer_storage_type%': 'memory',
```

when it set to "file", it will add define  "COBALT_MEDIA_BUFFER_STORAGE_TYPE_FILE=1" ,
But I did not find any source code about COBALT_MEDIA_BUFFER_STORAGE_TYPE_FILE , Whether this configuration is still valid?

Is there a better way to reduce memory, except as described in memory_tuning.md

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Cobalt currently doesn't support caching media buffers in file system.
Is it possible for you to tell us the purpose of the optimization?  Are you trying to make Cobalt support 4k playback on a system with limited memory, or are you trying to optimize the memory footprint of Cobalt just to see if it can take less resource on your target system?

Comment: niewei, what is the total memory and free memory?

Comment: sorry for update later.   the total memory is 1G and the free memory is about 250M to run cobalt at forground.

Comment: we have use all the  method at the memory_tuning.md  , base.gypi and reduce the cobalt_media_buffer_video_budget_4k . But I find the DecoderBufferAllocator allocate the buffer pools far beyond the set value when Seek  media (4K P60 360) forward.

Comment: 250MB sounds pretty low for 4k.  May I know how much you set |cobalt_media_buffer_video_budget_4k| to?

Comment: I set the cobalt_media_buffer_video_budget_4k to 50M(The default is 60M). and I find the DecoderBufferAllocator  will allocate about 80M when Seek media (4K P60 360) forward ceaseless.

Comment: Sorry for replying late.  Yes you need more memory than the stated budget to account for fragmentation.  Actually we also allocate lots of memory from the system heap to store DecoderBuffer object itself, as the DecoderBuffer object is allocated on heap.
I am still trying to reproduce your issue on our system.  And I will try to update you once I can reproduce it.  Meanwhile, can you tell me your schedule?  As I will be away for the next two weeks.